# ValidationError: mongoose validation failed

Tags: node.js, mongoose

ERRORS:

> (node:10164) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError:
>   product validation failed: oem: Path `oem` is required., category:
>   Path `category` is required.
>       at new ValidationError (C:\Projects\React\ninjas\neo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:30:11)
>       at model.Document.invalidate (C:\Projects\React\ninjas\neo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1957:32)
>       at p.doValidate.skipSchemaValidators (C:\Projects\React\ninjas\neo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1825:17)
>       at C:\Projects\React\ninjas\neo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:839:9
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9) (node:10164) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:10164) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

```
//Product.js(model)
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    oem: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default:Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = Product = mongoose.model('product', ProductSchema);
```

```js
//product.js(routes)
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

var Product = require('../models/Product');


router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  Product.find()
    .sort({ date: -1 })
    .then(prods => res.json(prods));
});

router.post('/newpro', (req, res) => {
    const newProduct = new Product({
      oem: req.body.oem,
      category: req.body.category
    });
    newProduct.save().then(prods => res.json(prods));
});



   

router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
  Product.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(prods => prods.remove().then(() => res.json({ success: true })))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ success: false }));
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
router.post('/newpro', (req, res) => {
    const newProduct = new Product({
      oem: req.body.oem,
      category: req.body.category
    });
    newProduct.save().then(prods => res.json(prods));
});
```

You are getting the values for `oem` and `category` from the body of the `HTTP POST` request.

The error is being raised because one of `req.body.oem` or `req.body.category` is `null`.

I don't know how you are simulating the `HTTP REQUEST` but double check it,

If your `HTTP REQUEST` looks good to you I have a 2nd guess, I see you are using no `body-parser middleware`, keep in mind that `req.body` is `undefined` by default.

From the docs:

> **req.body** .
>   Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By
>   default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use body-parsing
>   middleware such as body-parser and multer.

So perhaps changing your code to the following might fix your problem:

```
//product.js(routes)
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();


var bodyParser = require('body-parser');   
var Product = require('../models/Product'); 

router.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

// rest of the code
```

However it should have raised an error when you accessed `oem` or `category` in this case, as `req.body` is `undefined by default`. If you have any more info let us know.

Comment: Thank you very much  @Sid its working now but in place of express.use(bodyParser.json()); i wrote router.use(bodyParser.json()); because i initialize it with router thankyou once again you are like my superhero you save the day

Comment: @BakorKharkongor most welcome, just mark the question as answered ;)